# How to read a line into a char array when the line is longer than the array?

Tags: c++11, char

I tried to read a line into a char array with this:

```
char arr[3];
char arr2[3];
cin.getline(arr,3);
cout<<arr<<endl;
cin.getline(arr2,3);
cout<<arr2<<endl;
```

I entered something with 4 letters and the program yielded only the first 2 characters of arr without giving me a chance to input arr2,how can I avoid this from happening?

Comment: Try getting chars, not lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the impossible.

Take the length of the string before you create the destination array, then fire away.